# Shallow copy in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, copy

Pandas version 1.5.3

Problem: shallow copy should as result assign values from copied df, which on this example not working:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'A': [1,1, 1],
'B': [2,2, 2]
})
df2 = df.copy(False)
df['A'] = [10,10,10]
```

result:

```
df2 :
A B
1 2
1 2
1 2
```

Expected result:

```
df2:
A B
10 2
10 2
10 2
```

by the way, when I am doing this:

```
df['A'] += [10,10,10] # df2 result is correct
df2:
A B
10 2
10 2
10 2
```

also when I am changing specific value in series its also working

```
df['A'][0] = 10 
df2:
A  B
10 2
1  2
1  2
```

Could you explain why

this code: `df['A'] = [10,10,10]` is not updating data for shallow copy of this df and other provided examples works?

Comment: Not an explanation as to why, but instead of `df['A']`, consider `df.loc[:, 'A']`.

Comment: For me it works, try update your pandas version ? Change col A in df results in change in df2 (pandas version : '1.0.3')

Comment: @LaurentB. which version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

There is an explanation for this.
First of lets look what `df2 = df.copy(False)` means:

- When deep=False, a new object will be created without copying the
  calling object’s data or index (only references to the data and index
  are copied). Any changes to the data of the original will be
  reflected in the shallow copy (and vice versa).

This means if the values in df or df2 gets changed it will have effect on both dataframes.
The effects are visible when this command `df['A'] += [10,10,10]` or `df['A'] += 10` is used. It is only hard to see what happens because the 10s all look the same.

Lets try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'A': ["a","b", "c"],
'B': [2,2, 2]
})
df2 = df.copy(False)
df['A'] += "10"
```

now `df['A'] += "10"` returns for both dataframes:

```
     A  B
0  a10  2
1  b10  2
2  c10  2
```

But if df['A'] = ["c","d","e"] is used then you will get different outputs for df and df2. This is because now you have changed not **modified the **values**** of `["a","b","c"]` but you have replaced the **data and its reference** itself. See description from the beginning again.

Now lets come to `df.loc[:,'A'] = ["c","d","e"]`. How come this changes the values for both Dataframes? When using `df.loc[:,'A']` we select the Data with its Reference and replace its values by new Values. This is different from replacing the entire column `['A']` with new data which has no reference to the old data.

To learn the differences throughout it takes some experience since it is not always obvious why 2 seemingly identical commands act different.